# Cross-compile with Terry Guo's gcc-arm-none-eabi

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to test a cross compile using [Terry Guo's gcc-arm-none-eabi](http://launchpad.net/~terry.guo/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-arm-embedded). In a nutshell, here are the steps to install on Ubuntu:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi

The problem I am having is I can't find the documentation (or [I'm doing something wrong](https://superuser.com/questions/811772/access-man-page-for-package)). I know I can't ask for documentation or other off-site resources, so I'll cut right to the chase:

- What is the name of the compiler?
- Where is the compiler located?
- Where are the `arm-eabi` headers located?
- Where are the `arm-eabi` libs located?
- Where is the `arm-eabi` `sysroot` located?

---

```
$ find /usr -iname *arm-eabi*
$ find /usr -iname *gcc-arm*
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/gcc-arm-none-eabi
/usr/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi
$ info gcc-arm-none-eabi
No menu item `gcc-arm-none-eabi' in node `(dir)Top'.
$ man gcc-arm-none-eabi
No manual entry for gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

Comment: there's a bunch of stuff at https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

Comment: Thanks Keith. I've been through that link, and there's not much there that helps in practice. Here's the closest: [Could anyone give the starters a getting-start document?](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/212944), but it provides no useful information.

Comment: Keith - I take that back.... I just found this while searching for "C++": [User Manual](http://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/241412). Previously, I was searching for "documentation". Unfortunately, `dpkg -L` tells me that `readme.txt` is not present. Sigh...

Comment: The compiler prefix is `arm-none-eabi-`. This should help you find the other answers yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I got Debian's anemic arm embedded tools on Ubuntu 14; and not Terry Guo's tools even though I added Guo's PPA. This can be fixed with:

1. sudo apt-get remove binutils-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-none-eabi
2. sudo apt-get autoremove
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi=4-8-2014q2-0trusty10

---

With the proper package in place:

> What is the name of the compiler?
>   Where is the compiler located?

/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc and friends.

> Where are the arm-eabi headers located?
>   Where are the arm-eabi libs located?
>   Where is the arm-eabi sysroot located?

SYSROOT is /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/armv7-m.

I also needed to compile with `-mcpu=cortex-m3`, `-mthumb` and `--specs=nosys.specs`.

---

Related: Ubuntu will attempt to upgrade Guo's packages during a `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`. The behavior can be modified by pinning Guo's package. To pin Guo's package, add the following to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: binutils-arm-none-eabi
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: gcc-arm-none-eabi
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 900
```

Thanks to grawity on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for the information. See [Permanently block distro package installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/812253/permanently-block-distro-package-installation).